# Matrix of vector-by-vector sum-squared deviations of two matrices of column vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, mean-square-error

**Context**

I'm working on a Python program in which I will calculate some number $r$ of matrices $\mathbf{A}^i$ with identical dimensions $m\times n$. For this application, each matrix is probably best thought of as a collection of [$L^1$-normed](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/L1-Norm.html) column vectors $\mathbf{c}^i_j$ with strictly non-negative elements,

$$
\mathbf{A}^i = \left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
  | & \dots & | \\
  \mathbf{c}^i_1 & \dots & \mathbf{c}^i_n \\
  | & \dots & |
\end{array}
\right],
$$

where each element $c^i_{j,k}$ represents a fractional contribution of one of $m$ components to one of $n$ composite objects. For underlying structural reasons, I anticipate each column vector $\mathbf{c}^i_b$ to have a fairly unambiguous 'closest-match' column vector in both adjacent matrices, which may or may not fall at the same index $b$ in those neighboring matrices:

$$
\mathbf{c}^{i-1}_a \longleftrightarrow \mathbf{c}^i_b \longleftrightarrow \mathbf{c}^{i+1}_c \\
a \overset{?}{=} b \overset{?}{=}c
$$

I need to identify the complete set of these 'closest match' mappings.

At present, I am planning to use the element-wise sum-squared deviation (equivalently, since the dimension $m$ is constant among all the matrices, the mean-squared-deviation) between the pairs of column vectors in adjacent matrices as the metric for 'closest match':

$$
\delta^{i}_{b,c} = \sum_k{\left(c^i_{k,b}-c^{i+1}_{k,c}\right)^2}
$$

I plan to construct the $r-1$ matrices $\mathbf{\Delta}^i$ of these SSD values,

$$
\mathbf{\Delta}^i = \left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
\delta^i_{1,1} & \dots & \delta^i_{1,n} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\delta^i_{n,1} & \dots & \delta^i_{n,n} \\ 
\end{array}
\right],
$$

and then perform further manipulation on the $\mathbf{\Delta}^i$ to identify the desired mappings from each $\mathbf{A}^i$ to the next.

**Question**

Given such a set of matrices $\mathbf{A}^i$, what is an efficient way to generate the matrices $\mathbf{\Delta}^i$?  I would like to exploit basic linear algebra (transpose, matrix multiplication, etc.) to the extent possible. Alternatively, are there other 'closest-match' metrics I might use for which basic linear algebra would be well suited?

Answer (score 0):

The best way I've thought of to achieve this using the sum-squared deviation as the 'closest match' metric starts with rewriting the sum for $\delta^i_{b,c}$ by expanding the polynomial:

$$
\delta^i_{b,c} = \sum_{k}{\left[
    \left(c^i_{k,b}\right)^2
  - 2c^i_{k,b}c^{i+1}_{k,c}
  + \left(c^{i+1}_{k,c}\right)^2
\right]}
$$

The sums can then be split and reordered,

$$
\delta^i_{b,c} = \sum_{k}{\left(c^i_{k,b}\right)^2}
 + \sum_{k}{\left(c^{i+1}_{k,c}\right)^2}
 - 2 \sum_{k}{c^i_{k,b}c^{i+1}_{k,c}},
$$

and the matrix $\mathbf{\Delta}^i$ written as the sum of three contributions, all $n\times n$ matrices:

$$
\mathbf{\Delta}^i = \mathbf{X}^i + \mathbf{Y}^i - 2\mathbf{Z}^i
$$

The $\mathbf{Z}^i$ piece is the easiest, since by the definitions of [matrix multiplication](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MatrixMultiplication.html) and [transposition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Transpose.html):

$$
\mathbf{Z}^i = \left(\mathbf{A}^i\right)^\mathrm{T}\mathbf{A}^{i+1}
$$

Dealing with $\mathbf{X}^i$ and $\mathbf{Y}^i$ is problematic, though.  The form of both terms is quite familiar: each is the vector dot product of the relevant column vector $\mathbf{c}^i_b$ $\left(\mathbf{c}^{i+1}_c\right)$ with itself.  However, each $\mathbf{c}^i_b\cdot\mathbf{c}^i_b \left(\mathbf{c}^{i+1}_c\cdot\mathbf{c}^{i+1}_c\right)$ contributes to every element in row $b$ (column $c$) of $\mathbf{\Delta}^i$.

One way of writing $\mathbf{X}^i$ and $\mathbf{Y}^i$ is as follows:

$$
\mathbf{X}^i = \left[\begin{array}{ccc} \dots & | & \dots  \\
                   \dots & \mathbf{d}^i & \dots \\
                    \dots  & | & \dots  \end{array}\right] \\
\mathbf{Y}^i = \left[\begin{array}{ccc} \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
                  - & \mathbf{d}^{i+1} & - \\
                   \vdots  & \vdots & \vdots \end{array}\right] 
$$

Here, $\mathbf{d}^i$ is the column vector of dot products of the vectors $\mathbf{c}^i_j$, such that $d^i_j=\mathbf{c}^i_j\cdot\mathbf{c}^i_j$. How to obtain these vectors by 'basic' linear algebra, if possible, is not clear to me; nor was it clear to another, as-yet-unanswered [questioner](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/512146/dot-product-of-the-column-vectors-from-a-matrix-and-their-transposes-through-mat) two years ago.  Fortunately, as I am working in Python, [`numpy.diagonal`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diagonal.html) will readily extract the vectors $\mathbf{d}^i$ from $\left(\mathbf{A}^i\right)^\mathrm{T}\mathbf{A}^i$.  Also fortunately, Python's [`numpy.repeat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) is available as a means to stack together replicates of the $\mathbf{d}^i$ vectors into the needed matrices $\mathbf{X}^i$ and, after transposition, $\mathbf{Y}^i$.

While this approach will suit my needs, I'm wondering if there's a better way to obtain $\mathbf{X}^i$ and $\mathbf{Y}^i$, without performing 'matrix surgery' of this sort, to facilitate such calculations in languages with basic linear algebra support but without a rich set of matrix manipulation utilities like Python or MATLAB.

Comment: FWIW, I debated quite a bit whether to post this all into the question, or to split it into question and answer. Given that I have figured out a method that will work for my needs, I went the Q+A route. My apologies to any who are offended by this choice.